# Converting a DbSet to a DbSet<T> where T is the interface of the element type of the dbset

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I get my DbSet to DbSet from a DbSet.

```
  public IQueryable<T> GetData<T>() where T : class, IData
  { 
      var factory = EntityFrameworkConfiguration.TypeFactory[typeof(T)];
      var context = factory.Item2();         // context is a DbContext.
      var set = context.Set(factory.Item1);  //factory.Item1 is a Type object.
      return set.Cast<T>();

  }
```

factory.Item1 is the type of a Class that implements the Iterface T

simple case:

```
context.Set(typeof(MyClass));
how to return DbSet<IMyClass> ?
```

#### Update

Just adding alittle more information:

System.InvalidCastException: Cannot create a DbSet from a non-generic DbSet for objects of type 'AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper'. and the code:

```
[Title("AzureStoreSubscription"), DataScope("public"), KeyPropertyName("id_AzureStoreSubscriptionId"), ImmutableTypeId("{7a71540b-2eeb-32ae-a850-61c97e28df06}"), RelevantToUserType(UserType.Developer)]
public interface IAzureStoreSubscription : IData, IEntityFrameworkProvided
{
    // Properties
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.DateTime), ImmutableFieldId("{35977476-f662-528b-8236-e993b65796a5}")]
    DateTime dt_ChangedTime { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{cdc95aeb-a951-533c-87de-811fd4967ea6}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.DateTime)]
    DateTime dt_CreatedTime { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{83e0e743-0ec3-5f29-a4bd-14a1b97a13a8}")]
    DateTime? dt_DeletedTime { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid), ImmutableFieldId("{82f8da9f-00fa-5a00-b392-d47cb2d362d5}")]
    Guid id_AzureStoreSubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{3bbef642-c88b-5a13-be89-65d537de3eb6}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid)]
    Guid id_TenantId { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{273bd594-7aea-5ca0-b8da-4680a264bcfd}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string nvc_Email { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{64d29805-d76a-55b0-a61a-abb76b5fd096}")]
    string nvc_EntityState { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{a2172fef-de9a-559c-b33c-6c32d7f99727}")]
    string nvc_OptIn { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{e1bb5d48-2d72-5ffc-b86f-f78216ea4ee4}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string nvc_RawData { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{3e879595-9bbd-555f-8f63-f438e722915a}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string nvc_ResourceType { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{67bd2cba-9c36-594c-8586-39c71974e572}")]
    string nvc_SubscriptionId { get; set; }
}




public class C1AzureStoreRPContext : DbContext
{
    // Methods
    public C1AzureStoreRPContext(string connectionstring);

    // Properties
    public DbSet<AzureStoreResourceWrapper> AzureStoreResource { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper> AzureStoreSubscription { get; set; }
}




[Table("AzureStoreSubscriptions", Schema="cwac")]
public class AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper : AzureStoreSubscription, IAzureStoreSubscription, IData, IEntityFrameworkProvided
{
    // Fields
    private DataSourceId _dataSourceId;

    // Methods
    public AzureStoreSubscriptionWrapper();

    // Properties
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.DateTime), ImmutableFieldId("{35977476-f662-528b-8236-e993b65796a5}")]
    DateTime IAzureStoreSubscription.dt_ChangedTime { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{cdc95aeb-a951-533c-87de-811fd4967ea6}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.DateTime)]
    DateTime IAzureStoreSubscription.dt_CreatedTime { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{83e0e743-0ec3-5f29-a4bd-14a1b97a13a8}")]
    DateTime? IAzureStoreSubscription.dt_DeletedTime { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid), ImmutableFieldId("{82f8da9f-00fa-5a00-b392-d47cb2d362d5}")]
    Guid IAzureStoreSubscription.id_AzureStoreSubscriptionId { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{3bbef642-c88b-5a13-be89-65d537de3eb6}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.Guid)]
    Guid IAzureStoreSubscription.id_TenantId { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{273bd594-7aea-5ca0-b8da-4680a264bcfd}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_Email { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{64d29805-d76a-55b0-a61a-abb76b5fd096}")]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_EntityState { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{a2172fef-de9a-559c-b33c-6c32d7f99727}")]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_OptIn { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{e1bb5d48-2d72-5ffc-b86f-f78216ea4ee4}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_RawData { get; set; }
    [ImmutableFieldId("{3e879595-9bbd-555f-8f63-f438e722915a}"), StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50)]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_ResourceType { get; set; }
    [StoreFieldType(PhysicalStoreFieldType.String, 50), ImmutableFieldId("{67bd2cba-9c36-594c-8586-39c71974e572}")]
    string IAzureStoreSubscription.nvc_SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public DataSourceId DataSourceId { get; }
}
```

Comment: added the code. Its all created with codedom in a CMS.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not run the Cast method on the DbSet again?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696369(v=vs.113).aspx

So if the following is your DbSet:

```
var myClassSet = context.Set(typeof(MyClass));
```

You should be able to cast it like this:

```
return myClassSet.Cast<IMyClass>();
```

It should cast by a direct cast so it shouldn't have an issue casting to an inherited class. If that doesn't work, check out this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb2ba471-7a19-4886-854b-eb5c7ebfcf74/dbsett-and-casting?forum=csharplanguage

I hope that helps.

Comment: I get the error: 
"Cannot create a DbSet<IAzureStoreResource> from a non-generic DbSet for objects of type AzureStoreResourceWrapper." and AzureStoreResourceWrapper implements IAzureStoreResource. The context has DbSet<AzureStoreResourceWrapper> as a property.

Comment: I think my problem is some query inspectors after the cast that blows up. Sorry for the question.

Comment: This person has a similar problem, have you seen this StackOverflow post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609981/dbset-casttentity-error-cannot-create-a-dbsetientity-from-a-non-generic-d

Comment: I dont understand what they are doing, their answers are to limited for me to make it work.