# Iterating all Entity Framework DbSets that implement an Interface using reflection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, types, interface

Some of my Entity Framework classes implement a certain interface, say `IHasYearColumn`, which means the table has a `year` column (`int`).

I would like to iterate over all of the tables with year columns and do some work.

I managed to get the relevant types using:

```
 var typesWithYear = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
 .SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes())
 .Where(t=>typeof(IHasYearColumn).IsAssignableFrom(t);
```

I verified this works, and indeed I get all the types I want.

Now, I would like to iterate over the respective table get the year values from all the records:

```
foreach (t in typesWithYear)
   myDbEntites.Set<t>().Select(x=>x.Year);
```

This obviously won't compile since `t` is not recognized as `IHasYearColumn`. So, I tried casting all types in typesWithYear into `IHasYearColumn` but this would not help. I got an `InvalidCastException`.

Any ideas will be most welcomed.

**Edit**
Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25538087/4706282).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me. `IHaveSpecificIdNo` is my analog to the initial questions `IHasYearColumn`

```
    var currentSpecificId = "123";

var DataContext = this;
var setProps = DataContext
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(x => 
            {
                return x.PropertyType.IsGenericType 
                //todo better check
                &&  x.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("DbSet");
            })
            .ToArray();


            foreach (var setProperty in setProps)
            {
                var entityType = setProperty.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                var set = DataContext.Set(entityType);

                if (typeof (IHaveSpecificIdNo).IsAssignableFrom(entityType))
                {
                    var items = ((IQueryable<IHaveSpecificIdNo>)set)
                                    .Where(x => x.SpecificIdNo == currentSpecificId).ToArray();
                    if(items.Length == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //do something
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
foreach (t in typesWithYear)    
  myDbEntites.Set(t).AsQueryable().Cast<IHasYearColumn>().Select(x=>x.Year);
```

Comment: `InvalidCastException: Cannot create DbSet<IHasYearColumn> from a non-generic DbSet for objects of type ...`

Comment: Added `AsQueryable()`. Doesn't give a `DbSet` but you have a list to work on. I don't have an active project to test these but give it another try, why not :-)

Comment: `LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code for getting types include interface itself, so you need to add additional predicate:

```
 var typesWithYear = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                              .GetAssemblies()
                              .SelectMany(a=>a.GetTypes())
                              .Where(t=>typeof(IHasYearColumn)
                                          .IsAssignableFrom(t))
                              .Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract);
```

Next, use non-generic method for getting dbSet:

```
foreach (var type in typesWithYear)
{
    var set = myDbEntites.Set(type);

}
```

What's more, I'm not sure that EF will manage cast to an interface in order to produce SQL. If no (you can try it like GDS proposed), you can use Dynamic LINQ:

```
foreach (var type in typesWithYear)
{
    var set = myDbEntites.Set(type);
    yield return ((IQueryable)set).Select("Year")
                                  .Cast<int>(); // or sth else, your choice
}
```

EF supports casting to entity models or primitive type for sure.